# Convert REST content to comma seperated string

Tags: regex, c#-4.0, rest

I'm having some content in a REST API that I would like to convert into a simple comma-separated string - it looks as so:

```
{
  "2299": 2299,
  "2224": 2224,
  "2135": 2135,
  "2196": 2196,
  "2200": 2200
}
```

and this is how I do that:

```
foreach (var product in titles)
{
    TextBox1.Text = product["children"].ToString() + "<br/>";
}
```

This is ho I would like my output to look like:
`2299,2224,2135,2196,2200`

I've tried some various REGEX with no further luck - I'm using c# by the way...

Any idears...?

Comment: First i would Change the type of the Input: Ist just a list, so use a jsonArray (`[2299,2224,2135,2196,2200]`), not a jsonObject. and then you can simple replace `[` and `]` and you are done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved...!

By researching a few hours more on google I found the solution:

```
string c = product["children"].ToString();

foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(c, "(?<=\")[\\w]+(?!=\")"))
{
    string children = m.Value + ",";
}
```

This schript does the job for me... :)

Answer (score 1):

Using JSON.NET, you could simply do

```
var dict = JToken.Parse(textFromYourQuestion).ToObject<Dictionary<string, int>>().Values;
var stringYouWant = string.Join(",", dict.Values);
```